# how to make the blue border on the image disappears in IE

Tags: asp.net, cross-browser

so I have this image, that I linked to another page, here's the example:

[image: example]

the blue border suddenly appeared on the image that has links in them when I refreshed the page, it's only appeared in IE, other browser don't make the border appeared. what caused this? any idea?

Comment: I can't understand why someone would down-vote the question that I answer myself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution!

just add

```
border-style:none;
```

in your css style code, and cheers :D

Comment: Or just border: 0 or border: none - both are less characters to type!